# How to prevent PowerShell 7 Write-Error to write back literally the text "Write-Error"?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I run the following script in PowerShell 7:

```
Write-Error "Demo error message"
```

It writes (hopefully to the stderr):

> Write-Error: Demo error message

**Question**

How to prevent the leading "Write-Error: " literal? I would like to get just

> Demo error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this after running Write-Error:

```
(Get-Error).ErrorRecord.CategoryInfo

Category   : NotSpecified
Activity   : Write-Error
Reason     : WriteErrorException
```

It seems that the message you are presented in the console is constructed from `CategoryInfo.Activity` and `Exception.Message` joined with ": " string.

You can modify what Write-Error puts in CategoryInfo.Activity when it generates ErrorRecord:

```
Write-Error "Demo error message" -CategoryActivity 'xxx'
xxx: Demo error message
```

If you put $null or empty string it reverts back to "Write-Error" text, and when you use empty space the line starts with " : ", so that's not satisfying:

```
Write-Error "Demo error message" -CategoryActivity " "
 : Demo error message
```

But what if we put two backspaces in the message? It gets rid of those 3 characters.

```
Write-Error "`b`b`bDemo error message" -CategoryActivity " "
Demo error message
```

Even this works, but honestly I don' know why:

```
Write-Error "Demo error message" -CategoryActivity "`b`b"
Demo error message
```

You could also put enough backspaces to delete entire "Write-Error: " string:

```
Write-Error ("`b"*13 + 'Demo error message')
Demo error message
```

When you catch an error and do something with the message somewhere down the line, those backspaces are preserved:

```
try {Write-Error ("`b`b`bDemo error message") -ErrorAction Stop} catch {'The error is: ' + $_.Exception.Message}
The error iDemo error message
```

Works as required, definitely not recommended ;).

Answer (score 1):

If a terminating error is OK for you, you can use

```bsh
throw "Demo error message"
```

[about Throw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_throw?view=powershell-7)

[image]

Comment: Thx, I would like to continue, just write to the stderr